# Traversing Two Arrays with MongoDB's `$[]` Operator and Updating Relevant Docs

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After upgrading to Mongo 4.0 I am trying to make use of Mongo's new `$[]` functionality. What I'm basically trying to do is take in one or more "coverage" IDs and traverse two arrays to make updates filtered on matches to those passed in "coverage" IDs. The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
if (coverage) {
    let arrCoverage = [];
    arrCoverage = coverage.split(",");

    if (arrCoverage) {
      // convert each ID to a mongo ID
      let mongoArrCoverage = arrCoverage.map(coverage => new mongo.ObjectID(coverage));

      if (mongoArrCoverage) {
        try {
          let bulk = db.collection("customers").initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
          let count = 0;
          let batch = 1;

          db.collection("customers")
            .aggregate([
              {
                $match: {
                  "paymentOptions.coverages._id": {
                    $in: mongoArrCoverage
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $unwind: "$paymentOptions"
              },
              {
                $unwind: "$coverages"
              },
              {
                $match: {
                  "coverages._id": {
                    $in: mongoArrCoverage
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  coverages_id: "$coverages._id",
                  "coverages.status": "$coverages.status"
                }
              }
            ])
            .forEach(function(doc) {
              let coverages_id = doc.paymentOptions.coverages_id;
              bulk
                .find({
                  "paymentOptions.coverages._id": coverages_id
                })
                .updateOne({
                  $set: {
                    "paymentOptions.$[].coverages.$[].coverageEnd": lastDayOfMonth,
                    "paymentOptions.$[].coverages.$[].status": doc.paymentOptions.coverages.status == "active" ? null : doc.paymentOptions.coverages.status,
                    "paymentOptions.$[].coverages.$[].lastAdvanceDate": today
                  }
                });
              count++;
              if (count == batch) {
                bulk.execute();
                bulk = db.collection("customers").initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
                count = 0;
              }
            });

          if (count > 0) {
            bulk.execute();
          }

          res.sendStatus(200);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But this doesn't seem to be making the expected updates. I think the issue may be in the initial aggregation I do? Does this code look correct? In our previous model the "coverages" array was on the root of the document. Now that it's a a property within "paymentOptions", which is also an array, I assume I have to `$unwind` both of these arrays in my initial aggregation.

By the way, the relevant part of the document looks like this:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId>,
  someProp: <value>,
  paymentOptions: [
    {
     _id: <ObjectId>,
     otherProp: <value>,
     coverages: [
        {
          _id: <ObjectId>,  // Want to match on this
          coverageStart: <Date>,
          coverageEnd: <Date>, // Want to update this
          status: "active"
        },
        {
          _id: <ObjectId>, // Want to match on this
          coverageStart: <Date>,
          coverageEnd: <Date>, // Want to update this
          status: "active"
        }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document ?

Comment: Okay, a sample document has been added above.

Comment: Any ideas, @Veeram?

Comment: Just to clarify. do you need to update coverageEnd field ? It appears from your query you are updating more fields specifically the status field which is checking what is in the database.

Comment: Yes, I want to update the "status" field and the "coverageEnd" field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array filters. Also to unwind the nested arrays you have to use dot notation to include the entire path.

Something like should work

```
if (coverage) {
  let arrCoverage = [];
  arrCoverage = coverage.split(",");
  if (arrCoverage) {
    // convert each ID to a mongo ID
    let mongoArrCoverage = arrCoverage.map(coverage => new mongo.ObjectID(coverage));
    if (mongoArrCoverage) {
      try {
        let bulk = db.collection("customers").initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        let count = 0;
        let batch = 1;
        db.collection("customers").aggregate([{
          $match: {
            "paymentOptions.coverages._id": {
              $in: mongoArrCoverage
            }
          }
        }, {
          $unwind: "$paymentOptions"
        }, {
          $unwind: "$paymentOptions.coverages"
        }, {
          $match: {
            "paymentOptions.coverages._id": {
              $in: mongoArrCoverage
            }
          }
        }, {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            "paymentOptions_id": "$paymentOptions._id",
            "coverages_id": "$paymentOptions.coverages._id",
            "coverages_status": "$paymentOptions.coverages.status"
          }
        }]).forEach(function(doc) {
            let paymentOption_id = doc.paymentOptions_id;
            let coverages_id = doc.coverages_id;
            let status = doc.coverages_status;
            bulk.find({}).arrayFilters([
                {"po._id": paymentOption_id},
                {"cr._id":  coverages_id}]).updateOne({
                $set: {
                  "paymentOptions.$[po].coverages.$[cr].coverageEnd": lastDayOfMonth,
                  "paymentOptions.$[po].coverages.$[cr].status": status == "active" ? null : status,
                  "paymentOptions.$[po].coverages.$[cr].lastAdvanceDate": today
                }
              }); count++;
              if (count == batch) {
                bulk.execute();
                bulk = db.collection("customers").initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
                count = 0;
              }
            });
          if (count > 0) {
            bulk.execute();
          }
          res.sendStatus(200);
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Will try this, thanks. Syntax error here:             
`bulk.find({}).arrayFilters([{
                "po._id": paymentOption_id,
                "cr._id": coverages_id]).updateOne({`

Comment: Np. Not sure what the error is but I updated the answer. Give it a try again.

Comment: Cool. That fixed the error. Plugging this in now. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error: TypeError: bulk.find(...).arrayFilters is not a function

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if you're using any library. I do see something like [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/). You may need to adjust the code to your library.

Comment: I checked my package.json, and I have this:  "mongodb": "^2.2.26". Thinking this might be my issue.

Comment: You definitely have to update to 3.x mongodb librrary node version( latest is 3.1.9 ) and figure out a right way to pass array filters. I will look around too.

Comment: Thanks. Update: I upgraded to 3.1.9. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Try passing as option. Something like `bulk.updateOne({},{                 $set: {                   "paymentOptions.$[po].coverages.$[cr].coverageEnd": lastDayOfMonth,                   "paymentOptions.$[po].coverages.$[cr].status": status == "active" ? null : status,                   "paymentOptions.$[po].coverages.$[cr].lastAdvanceDate": today                 }               },  {arrayFilters:   [  {"po._id": paymentOption_id},                 {"cr._id":  coverages_id}]} )`

Comment: Hi @Veeram, unfortunately this didn't work either. I've tried some other changes and have an updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266088/array-filters-not-working-as-expected-in-mongo-node-backend